# Need a little help to generate p12 cert

Tags: openssl, certificate, keytool, pkcs#12, p12

I need a little help to generate a PKCS#12 file using OpenSSL (or other tool).
Generally, I used keytool from JDK and this syntax:

```
keytool -genkey -alias friendly_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storepass mypassword -storetype pkcs12 -keystore c:\my_cert.p12
```

But I can't find the similar syntax in OpenSLL.

I'll be grateful for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Openssl has the [`pkcs12`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/pkcs12.html) command for adding certificates in the PKCS#12 format.

You could try something like this to simulate the whole flow (although you might already have certificates to import in the pkcs12 bundle)

**Generate the certificate (only for this example)**

[How to generate a self-signed SSL Certificate using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl?rq=1)

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

This should create 2 files, key.pem with the private key and a cert.pem with the x509v2 certificate (note this command produces x509v2 certs which are kind of old and should not be used. since the motive of this answer is not to show how to generate valid certificates, I am using this dummy example)

**Add the above key and cert to your pkcs12 bundle**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out foo.p12 -export -name friendly_name
```

Both the steps are going to ask for the private key password and the pkcs12 container password, keep a track of those passwords.

**Verify that the cert has been stored**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -nokeys -info
```

This should print out something like

```
MAC Iteration 2048
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 7E D3 2E ED 1A 3A 67 1E 90 4A AD 15 8D D9 C6 7A 11 EE E6 0A
    friendlyName: friendly_name
subject=/C=IN/ST=KA/CN=foo.example.com
issuer=/C=IN/ST=KA/CN=foo.example.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE5DCCAswCCQC/nYhnwGT1HzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA0MQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ
    ---SNIPPED---
MkvKFwTL+ZQ=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
```

Notice the friendly name in the output.

Answer (score 0):

We need the SSL certificate (file with extexsion `.cer` or `.crt`) and the key certificate (file with extension `.key`) to generate `.p12` file.

Run this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.cer -inkey certificate.key -name personal -out file.p12
```

- **`-in certificate.cer`**: the certificate private key
- **`-inkey certificate.key`**: the certificate public key. Could be a `.crt` file instead
- **`-name`**: Could specify a optional name
- **`-out`**: p12 File name that openssl command will generate